# How can I solve MUI GridActionsCellItem types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, material-ui

I am using @mui/x-data-grid package in my react app and after upgrading to the latest version,I started getting a type error **GridActionsCellItem** component.

Below is my Code

```
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      { field: 'displayName', headerName: 'Name', minWidth: 100, flex: 1 },
      {
        field: 'actions',
        type: 'actions',
        width: 70,
        getActions: params => [<GridActionsCellItem icon={<DeleteIcon />} label="Delete" />]
      }
    ],
    [programData, programTeamsData, rolesData]
  );
```

Below is the Type Error.

```
Type '{ icon: Element; label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ((Pick<{ label: string; icon?: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>; } & ... 4 more ... & Omit<...>, "action" | ... 283 more ... | "showInMenu"> | Pick<...>) & RefAttributes<...>)'.
  Type '{ icon: Element; label: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<{ label: string; icon?: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>; } & { showInMenu: true; } & { autoFocus?: boolean; classes?: Partial<...>; ... 5 more ...; sx?: SxProps<...>; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>, "action" | ... 276 more ... | "divider">': onResize, onResizeCapture, showInMenu
```

I have tried to update all my packages to the latest version but  still get this error.
According to me, I should not be getting this error because GridActionsCellItem expects an icon and label items which i have passed.

I have also tried to pass an onClick attribute but i ge the same error. Below is an example.
[image].

Kindly help me understand where i might be going wrong. Thank you

Comment: Please upload your full page of the code section